# android - set up a counter

Tags: java, android

For my new game I need a counter which shows the current score. I have four shapes and these shapes are filled with colors from a list which are chosen randomly. If the first shape is filled with the color red the counter should increase, otherwise it shouldn't. I tried to implement it, but the counter doesn't count and I don't know what's the fault.

```
public class GameScreen extends Activity implements OnGestureListener{      
    private Paint paint = new Paint();              
    public int score = 0;              
    TextView text;
    public int colora;
    public int colorb;
    public int colorc;
    public int colord;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW);
        Collections.shuffle(numbers);

        colora = numbers.get(0);
        colorb = numbers.get(1);
        colorc = numbers.get(2);
        colord = numbers.get(3);

        if(colora == Color.RED){
            score = score++;
        }

        TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        score.setText(String.valueOf(score));

    }
}
```

Comment: You should really give meaningful names to your variables.

Comment: print the value ca and see

Comment: It prints out a value between -256 and -1611867...  don't know what it tells me

Comment: Why is it always red? I thought it allocates it randomly?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you increase the `score` counter every time onCreate is called. Why would you want that? onCreate is only called when the app is started or the user resumes to the app which has been killed by the system before.

Comment: I restart it to allocate the colors again to the shapes in another order

Answer (score 1):

The `x++` operator increment the value of the variable and then return the value as it was before the incrementation. So when you write `score = score++` you are incrementing `score` and then immediatly overwriting the value with the value from before the incrementation which means it will always be zero.

Comment: With what do I replace it then? `++x`?

Comment: Just remove the affectation so it is just `score++`

Comment: Okay, I tested it. It starts counting, but not correctly: sometimes it adds two, and sometimes it increments, even when the first shape is not red

Comment: For the multiple time it seems like a lifecycle issue. onCreate is probably created several time. And for the incrementation always happening, it is  what your code says and not the ++. `numbers` is created with predefined value so colorA will always be red in your case

Comment: It is created several times, yes. Is there a way to let it count correctly then?

Comment: I believe that would be for another question. But to help you with your initial search you can read this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html and this https://www.google.ca/search?q=android+lifecycle&client=firefox-b-ab&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS0NTg-vHQAhVCvhQKHWEqCKsQ_AUICCgB&biw=1429&bih=1020&dpr=0.9#imgrc=O8bNSw7AkWVoKM%3A

Comment: Can you give a hint what I need to do, anyway?

Comment: In a comment, no. Not enough space. Read and search the web a bit, think about it try something and if you need more help post another question.

Comment: Could you tell me what's the problem with the counter, when I avoid restarting onCreate? Why does it count more or less 'randomly' then?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add 1 to your variable you type : score++;  or score = score + 1;
not score = score ++;